# jquery checkbox plugin not initialising on datatables pagination

Tags: jquery, checkbox, pagination, datatables

I have a Datatables table set up with one column using the Switchery iPhone switch plugin for checkboxes which works great. However, when using pagination, on the second (or subsequent) page(s) the plugin isn't initialised. Here is the initialisation code for Switchery:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

    elems.forEach(function(html) {
      var switchery = new Switchery(html, { color: '#00a45a', secondaryColor: '#8f0a05' });
    });
```

I've tried this:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination li a').click(function() {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

        elems.forEach(function(html) {
          var switchery = new Switchery(html, { color: '#00a45a', secondaryColor: '#8f0a05' });
        });
    });
```

But obviously it re-initialises the checkbox when going back to the first page so there are then 2 switches and an extra switch each time etc.

So I tried adding a class of "switched" on init like so:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

    elems.forEach(function(html) {
      var switchery = new Switchery(html, { color: '#00a45a', secondaryColor: '#8f0a05' });
      $('.js-switch').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('switched');
      });
    });
```

And then filtering out on paginate like this:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination li a').click(function() {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch:not([class="switched"])'));
        console.log(elems);

        elems.forEach(function(html) {
          var switchery = new Switchery(html, { color: '#00a45a', secondaryColor: '#8f0a05' });
        });
    });
```

But that isn't working, I'm sure it's something simple with the :not()? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Rob.

Comment: Your code would be easier to follow if you: 1) Made better use of jQuery (instead of calling `querySelectorAll` and `Array.prototype.slice`). 2) Used a function to encapsulate code that never changes.  That way, when you compare two code snippets, we aren't distracted by working code that isn't causing a problem, and we can focus only on the differences that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the attribute selector, use the class selector:

```
'.js-switch:not(.switched)'
```

The selector you have is impossible.  Or, rather, the `:not()` portion would always match, even if the element has a `switched` class.  You are saying, "get me elements that have a class of 'js-switch' and whose class attribute is exactly 'switched'."  If the class attribute is exactly 'switched', it cannot also have a class of 'js-switch'.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Just while I'm here, is this the best way of doing what I'm trying to do or do you think there might be a more efficient way?

Comment: @RobMcKinney - Look at the [`fnCreatedRow`](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnCreatedRow) callback that dataTables provides.  You can then act on newly created rows only, rather than searching the whole document and you shouldn't need the `:not()` selector at all.